# Access variables between commands with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this (overly simplified) Discord bot

```
voting_enabled = False

@bot.command()
async def start():
    voting_enabled = True

@bot.command()
async def finish():
    voting_enabled = False

@bot.command()
async def vote():
    if voting_enabled:
        # Do something
    else:
        # Do something else
```

### The problem

When I call call the `vote()` command, it always goes through the else part of the code. Even after calling the `start()` command

### What I want to achieve

I want that the `vote()` command behave differently depending on if the other two commands where called previously

### What I tried

I tried using the `global` keyword like this on the first line

```
global voting_enabled
voting_enabled = False
```

But it did nothing

Comment: Sorry, how do you know that "both `start()` and `finish() `commands are not changing the voting_enabled value"? Your tasks are asynchronous, so how do you know `voting_enabled` wasn't turned on and then off?

Comment: @ubadub When I call the `vote()` command, it always goes through the else part. Even after calling the `start()`

Comment: When/where is `finish()` is called? I assume you've left out code since you said it's overly simplified.

Comment: `finish()` is called from a user when the voting has finished. It's not relevant to the problem, I think. The calling order is `start()` > `vote()` > `finish()`, where `vote()` can be called many times.

Comment: How did you use the `global` keyword?

Comment: @Wright, I will update the question showing what I did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `global` keyword was not used correctly.

`global` should be defined within every function.

Example:

```
voting_enabled = False

@bot.command()
async def start():
    global voting_enabled

    voting_enabled = True

@bot.command()
async def finish():
    global voting_enabled

    voting_enabled = False

@bot.command()
async def vote():
    global voting_enabled

    if voting_enabled:
        # Do something
    else:
        # Do something else
```

Answer (score 16):

Except don't use globals because they stinky. Discord.py has another way to do this.

```
bot.voting_enabled = False

@bot.command()
async def start():
    bot.voting_enabled = True

@bot.command()
async def finish():
    bot.voting_enabled = False

@bot.command()
async def vote():
    if bot.voting_enabled:
        # Do something
    else:
        # Do something else
```