# Python Discord ChatBot: Making a mood counter

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a mood counter for my discord ChatBot. This variable should influence responses to the user. I made two dictionaries in python so far, one called responses and one called insults. The responses are straightforward, with the bot replying if the user sent a message that was in the dictionary. The insult dictionary subtracts a set amount from the variable mood every time you insult the bot. I wrote an if statement trying to subtract the mood by a little bit but whenever I try actually insulting the bot, the bot doesn't say anything to me. Please help. Keep in mind this is not all the code and I am willing to provide a more in-depth explanation as to what problem I have.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message) :
    content = message.content.upper()
    mood = 2
    if content in responses:
        if mood <= 0:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, responses[content]["RANG"])
        if mood == 1:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, responses[content]["ANG"])
        if mood == 2:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, responses[content]["NEU"])
        if mood == 3:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, responses[content]["HAP"])
        if mood == 4:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, responses[content]["RHAP"])
    if content in insults:
        mood = mood - 0.25
        if mood <= 0:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["RANG"])
        if mood == 1:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["ANG"])
        if mood == 2:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["NEU"])
        if mood == 3:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["HAP"])
        if mood == 4:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["RHAP"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange code you have, because you set `mood=2` all the time in line 4.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message) :
    content = message.content.upper()

    mood = 2 # you hard-code your mood here!

    if content in responses: # might enter here

        if mood <= 0: # mood = 2, so won't enter here
            await client.send_message(message.channel, responses[content]["RANG"])

        if mood == 1: # mood = 2, so won't enter here
            await client.send_message(message.channel, responses[content]["ANG"])

        if mood == 2: # mood = 2, so ALWAYS here!
            await client.send_message(message.channel, responses[content]["NEU"])

        if mood == 3: # mood = 2, so won't enter here
            await client.send_message(message.channel, responses[content]["HAP"])

        if mood == 4: # mood = 2, so won't enter here
            await client.send_message(message.channel, responses[content]["RHAP"])

    if content in insults: # might enter here
        mood = mood - 0.25 # mood was 2, not it is 1.75

        if mood <= 0: # mood = 1.75, so won't enter here
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["RANG"])

        if mood == 1: # mood = 1.75, so won't enter here
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["ANG"])

        if mood == 2: # mood = 1.75, so won't enter here
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["NEU"])

        if mood == 3: # mood = 1.75, so won't enter here
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["HAP"])

        if mood == 4: # mood = 1.75, so won't enter here
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["RHAP"])
```

From somewhere you need to extract the `mood`. Where does it come from?

Also, you are using `floats` but your checks are all `== <some_int>`. You might want to change all the `if mood == <int>` to `elif mood <= <int>`.

```
    if content in insults: # might enter here
        mood = mood - 0.25 # mood was 2, now it is 1.75

        if mood <= 0: # mood = 1.75, so won't enter here
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["RANG"])

        elif mood <= 1: # mood = 1.75, so won't enter here
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["ANG"])

        elif mood <= 2: # mood = 1.75, so ENTER HERE
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["NEU"])

        elif mood <= 3: # elif, so skipped
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["HAP"])

        elif mood <= 4: # elif, so skipped
            await client.send_message(message.channel, insults[content]["RHAP"])
```

## Make the mood global

Your `mood` is being reset every time. To avoid this, try [Access variables between commands with discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955125/access-variables-between-commands-with-discord-py):

```
mood = 2
@client.event
async def on_message(message) :
    content = message.content.upper()

    global mood

    if content in responses:
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: I hard coded the mood to start off at two because that's a 'neutral' point. Whenever the bot gets insulted, I want it to subtract 0.25 of the mood. So if the bot get insulted enough, the mood will decrease. And thanks for showing me what to do for the mood responses.

Comment: ok, so you might want to make the `mood` variable more global and update it every time you get a new response... Now, every time you get to the function, you reset the mood to `2`.

Comment: I tried making the variable more global before I asked the question, but it didn't seem to work. Whenever I tested it, it would say that local variable mood referenced before assignment. I think it thinks that I'm trying to declare the variable inside the function, but that's not the case.

Comment: Also, now whenever I insult it, it works and responds but the mood doesn't go down because it is reset whenever the function is called. Any advice?

Comment: can you put the line `mood = 2` outside the function (i.e. before the line `@client.event`)?

Comment: I just tried that, it worked the same as before but now there was an error so I just put it back inside the function.

Comment: The same one, it said that I declared the local variable mood before assignment.

Comment: Check my edit in the bottom of the answer and see if it works

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955125/access-variables-between-commands-with-discord-py

Comment: I even made a way to compliment the bot and get it's mood higher.

Comment: Awesome man. Let me know if you bot ever goes live. Would like to see it!