# Creating and changing global variable with async in Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Is there a way that I can 1. Create a variable that can be used by different `async def command(ctx, *, arg` commands? such as

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is online and ready.')
    #creates the global variable called like "baseNumberID"
async def command(ctx, *, arg):
    baseNumberID =+ 1
bot.run("TOKEN")
```

So what i want, is to have a variable created on launch that can then be changed/edited and/or added on to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can create module level variables and access them with the "global" keyword just like a non-asyncio function. The standard variable scoping rules apply like any other python function. Since your question isn't specific to `discord` and I don't happen to have `discord`, I've just updated a standard asyncio "hello world" program.

```
import asyncio

foo = 0

async def say(what, when):
    await asyncio.sleep(when)
    global foo
    foo += 1
    print(what, foo)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(say('hello world', 1))
loop.close()
```

Comment: I tried to incoperate this into my code, and it still says `local variable 'baseNumberID' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Did you include `global baseNumberID` at the top all functions that try to reassign it? As an aside, I noticed `baseNumberID =+ 1` which just assigns `+1` to the variable. Incrementing is `baseNumberID += 1`.

Comment: I will show some later if wanted, but if your making a discord bot you should make anything you want as a global variable an attribute of `bot`. You should check this out for usage on it, doing it this way also simplifies your code a fair bit. 
[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59917242/13781503)

Comment: @EthanM-H - that's a good observation for OP's `discord` code. I was just focusing on the general async question.