# Is there a way for my discord bot to be used with one person at a time?

Tags: python, discord, bots

im making a guessing game bot in python, but multiple people can use the bot at the same time. can i limit it to one person at a time that can use the bot?  im hoping for something thats relatively easy to understand (if thats possible).

(im a beginner at python btw)

```
import keep_alive
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import sys

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
number = random.randint(1, 100)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is online")



@client.command()
async def numpuz(ctx):
  global steps
  await ctx.send("Type a starting number")
  steps = 0
  steps = 1
  global number
  print(number)
  global lives
  lives = 8
      
  @client.command()
  async def num(ctx, guessednumber):
    global steps
    global number
    global lives

        
    if int(guessednumber) > number: 
      if steps == 1:
        await ctx.send("Try again you were to high")
        lives = lives - 1
        if lives == 0:
          await ctx.send("YOU LOST")
          steps = 0
              
    elif int(guessednumber) < number:
      if steps == 1:
        await ctx.send("Try again you were to low")
        lives = lives - 1
        if lives == 0:
          await ctx.send("YOU LOST")
          steps = 0
            
    else:
      if steps == 1:
        await ctx.send("YOU WON")
        steps = 0
        number = random.randint(1, 100)
        await ctx.send("You had " +str(lives)+ " lives left")
        comm.reset_cooldown(ctx)
   

keep_alive.keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv("token"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, it is inadvisable to use global variables like the way you are currently doing, and that's why you have to explicitly declare `global` every time. It is better practice to instead create a class for your numbers game and then import it in, because then you can use class attributes instead of global variables, and it is better code organization.

However, DiscordPy also provides another way of using "global" variables, which you can read about in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59917242/14667331). Basically, you can do

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
bot.variable_name = 42

@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx):
   print(bot.variable_name)

>> 42

@bot.command()
async def bar(ctx):
   bot.variable_name = "cheese"
   print(bot.variable_name)

>> "cheese"
```

As for the limiting to one user, you can do something like keeping track of the user ID of the user to started the bot command, and whenever someone tries to use the bot command, check if they have the same ID:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
bot.allowed_id = "Not in use!"  

@bot.command()
async def numpuz(ctx):
   author = ctx.message.author

   if bot.allowed_id == "Not in use!":
      bot.allowed_id = author.id

   if bot.allowed_id != author.id:
      return   

   # The rest of your function here
```

The same snippet would be added to your `num()` function. And don't forget to set `bot.allowed_id` back to "Not in use!" after someone is done with the commands, such as losing the game.

*Ps, the Discord client and bot are separate things, so you should use another variable name to avoid confusion. Something like `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")` would be better.

Comment: omg this  is just what i needed.  thank you so much  for the  tip and the help. :)